# How to write data in three XML files with same structures?

Tags: php, xml

I have this task that I have three XML files in different folders, and when write a data from form in php to save it at all xml files in each directory.

So I have one desicion that make my code so big :

```
$xml = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml -> load('book.xml');
$xml2->load("../file_tree/files/book.xml");
$xml3->load("../file_tree/files/Book/book.xml");

 $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagname('root')->item(0);
 $rootTag = $xml2->getElementsByTagname('root')->item(0);
 $rootTag = $xml3->getElementsByTagname('root')->item(0);


$bookTag = $xml->createElement("book"); 
$bookTag = $xml2->createElement("book"); 
$bookTag = $xml3->createElement("book");
```

..... and others tags in XML third times and this make my code so big ...If somebody know more easy way to stored data  in this XML files I will be happy to share it

Comment: make a function and call it with each XML file.

Comment: Dormilich thats good idea I forget it that I can call every xml file with function separately. I will share the code when I make the function. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution with 2 XML files in different directories that saved from one form:

In index . php

```
<?phpinclude 'insert.php';

$xml1 = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");

$xml1 -> load('../file_tree/files/example.xml');
  get_xml($xml1);
$xml1->save('../file_tree/files/example.xml');

$xml2 = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");

$xml2 -> load('../file_tree/files/Books/example.xml');
 get_xml($xml2);
$xml2->save('../file_tree/files/Books/example.xml');?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php function get_xml($xml){
```

if(isset($_GET['insert']))
{

```
$date= date('Y-m-d');



$b_author = $_GET['author'];
$b_name =$_GET['name'];
//$b_date= date('Y m d');

$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagname('root')->item(0);

$bookTag = $xml->createElement("book"); 

    $authorTag = $xml->createElement("author",$b_author);
    $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name",$b_name);
    //$dateTag = $xml->createElement($b_date);
    $dateTag = $xml->createElement('date', $date);

    $bookTag->appendChild($authorTag);
    $bookTag->appendChild($nameTag);
    $bookTag->appendChild($dateTag);

$rootTag->appendChild($bookTag);

   }}
```